# Mobile Check Method doesn't work on some browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, mobile, http-headers, redirect

I am using the method below to check if mobile version but it doesn't always work on all desktop browsers and its not a matter of IE versions, coz some machines has IE9 and it stayed on my desktop version and some other machines with IE9 redirected to the mobile version when i should always return false from PC and the same happened with some IE8 users

Is there any exceptions with this method ?

```
        public static bool IsMobile()
        {
            //GETS THE CURRENT USER CONTEXT
            HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

            //FIRST TRY BUILT IN ASP.NT CHECK
            if (context.Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice)
            {
                return true;
            }
            //THEN TRY CHECKING FOR THE HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE HEADER
            if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_WAP_PROFILE"] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
            //THEN TRY CHECKING THAT HTTP_ACCEPT EXISTS AND CONTAINS WAP
            if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"] != null &&
            context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_ACCEPT"].ToLower().Contains("wap"))
            {
                return true;
            }
            //AND FINALLY CHECK THE HTTP_USER_AGENT 
            //HEADER VARIABLE FOR ANY ONE OF THE FOLLOWING
            if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"] != null)
            {
                //Create a list of all mobile types
                string[] mobiles = {
"midp", "j2me", "avant", "docomo", 
"novarra", "palmos", "palmsource", 
"240x320", "opwv", "chtml",
"pda", "windows ce", "mmp/", 
"blackberry", "mib/", "symbian", 
"wireless", "nokia", "hand", "mobi",
"phone", "cdm", "up.b", "audio", 
"SIE-", "SEC-", "samsung", "HTC", 
"mot-", "mitsu", "sagem", "sony"
, "alcatel", "lg", "eric", "vx", 
"NEC", "philips", "mmm", "xx", 
"panasonic", "sharp", "wap", "sch",
"rover", "pocket", "benq", "java", 
"pt", "pg", "vox", "amoi", 
"bird", "compal", "kg", "voda",
"sany", "kdd", "dbt", "sendo", 
"sgh", "gradi", "jb", "dddi", 
"moto", "iphone"
};

                //Loop through each item in the list created above 
                //and check if the header contains that text
                foreach (string s in mobiles)
                {
                    if (context.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].ToLower().Contains(s.ToLower()))
                    {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
```

Comment: Using unchecked user-agent sniffing like this is almost guaranteed to give you false-positives and false-negatives. The User-Agent string is extensible via all sorts of installed software, and your checks are too broad. For instance "Avant" will likely hit AvantBrowser, a desktop browser, and several of your other two-character checks could certainly be found in extension tokens of the UA string. We've seen this happen in-the-wild.

Answer (score 1):

If I don´t need to use device capabilities (normaly WURFL), then I use this [code](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/download/cs). Maybe you could complete your code with this regex.

Answer (score 0):

ok i found a work around 
i added more check

```
if (context.Request.UserAgent.ToLower().Contains("pc"))
            {
                return false;
            }
```

Comment: Where did you add that? It's going to result in a false-negative on PocketPC.